# Parallelize API calls in R

Tags: r

I'm building a project for Bitcoin data collection through a Bitfinex API. The thing is, I want to store data in 10 second intervals but the average server response for each call is 12 seconds ( sometimes taking up to 80 seconds ).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
while(TRUE){

  # Request API data
  ticker    <- fromJSON( file = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd" )
  orderbook <- fromJSON( file = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/book/" )

  # Clean, format and insert data into SQL Database
}
```

I wonder if there's any way to parallelise it, e.g., if a request reaches 10 seconds, another concurrent API request is made. Since it will take 80 seconds tops for one response, I think that a max of 8-10 simultaneous requests would have to be a possibility.

Comment: The R interpreter is single threaded, making this a challenging task for R.  Have you considered using a technology for data collection that is better suited to processing real time data streams, such as Apache Kafka? Ideally you would use a technology suited to real time streams to collect the data, and then analyze it with R.

Comment: Did a quick search, it will indeed solve my situation. I'll have a deeper look into it. Thank you!

Comment: There's also an R pkg to interface with Kafka, too: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rkafka/index.html